# Android Kotlin Click Event for Back Button in Action Bar

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to get action after pressing back button in top toolbar

```
class TagsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.title = "$selectedItemText Tags"
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
        val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            Log.d(InTorry.TAG, "TagsFragment: back BTN Pressed")
        }

    }
 }
```

Unfortunately, it doest log anything

I found I should add OnBackPressedCallback but it doesnt work as well :

```
class TagsFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val selectedItemText = arguments?.getString("selectedItemText")//get arguments
        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.title = "$selectedItemText Tags"
       (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)


        (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(
            this,
            object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    Log.d(InTorry.TAG, "Fragment back pressed invoked")
                    // Do custom work here

                    // if you want onBackPressed() to be called as normal afterwards
                    if (isEnabled) {
                        isEnabled = false
                        requireActivity().onBackPressed()
                    }
                }
            }
        )
}
```

Kind regards
Jack

Answer (score 0):

```
put this in onCreate method
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
//and then override this method and find id.
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have full of errors

Comment: It should be (activity as AppCompatActivity?)?.supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true). I understand back button is part of activity menu(all menus)?

Answer (score 0):

I know sometimes it is painful when android just deprecates on of their on Event functions ,Anyways this is your code :

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

and you can just remove the onClickListener Interface and shortcut it if you desire like this :

```
 toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
                requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
     }
```

should be working fine

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all
The code I use now:

1. For device back button, in Activity onCreate()

class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)


    onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            Log.d(InTorry.TAG,"device back btn click")
            //finish()
        }
    })
```

2. Toolbar Back Button arrow - Now I know that it works like one big menu

   ```
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {// this is my back button - simply home

            Log.d(InTorry.TAG,"Toolbar Back BTN Click")

           ...
        }
        R.id.top_menu_settings -> {
            Log.d(InTorry.TAG,"top_menu_settings click")
            true
        }
        R.id.top_menu_logout -> {
            Log.d(InTorry.TAG,"top_menu_logout click")
            Firebase.auth.signOut()
            gotoLogin()
            true
        }


        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

   }
   ```